# What's the difference between([])+ and []+?

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> sentence = "Thomas Jefferson began building Monticello at the age of 26."
>>> tokens1 = re.split(r"([-\s.,;!?])+", sentence)
>>> tokens2 = re.split(r"[-\s.,;!?]+", sentence)
>>> tokens1 = ['Thomas', ' ', 'Jefferson', ' ', 'began', ' ', 'building', ' ', 'Monticello', ' ', 'at', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'age', ' ', 'of', ' ', '26', '.', '']
>>> tokens2 = ['Thomas', 'Jefferson', 'began', 'building', 'Monticello', 'at', 'the', 'age', 'of', '26', '']
```

Can you explain the purpose of `(` and `)`?

Comment: Inside a regular expression, `(..)` is a "capture group" and `[..]` is a "character class". The documentation will explain what these mean (and how capture groups apply to split) in more detail.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) before asking here.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, but why would simply _capturing_ `([...])` change what is matched?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `(..)` changes the behavior of `split`. Hence the follow-on sentence. There is definitely some duplicates..

Comment: If you want the group to not affect the split you can use `(?:)`

Comment: Anyway, the documentation excerpt (already linked above) here: ["*If capturing parentheses are used* in pattern, then *the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned* as part of the resulting list."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it doesn't change what is matched.  exactly the same things are matched.  it does, however, change what split returns (a very different thing)

Comment: You may find [this reference on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) helpful in future

Comment: @ysth I am novice in Python.  In Java, there would be no difference, and perhaps the OP is also coming from a different background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(..)` in a regex denotes a *capturing group* (aka "capturing parenthesis"). They are used when you want to extract values out of a pattern. In this case, you are using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) function which behaves in a specific way when the pattern has capturing groups. According to the documentation:

> re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)
>
> Split string by the occurrences of pattern. **If capturing parentheses
>   are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are
>   also returned as part of the resulting list.**

So normally, the delimiters used to split the string are not present in the result, like in your second example. However, if you use `()`, the text captured in the groups will also be in the result of the split. This is why you get a lot of `' '` in the first example. That is what is captured by your group `([-\s.,;!?])`.

Answer (score 1):

With a capturing group (`()`) in the regex used to split a string, split will include the captured parts.

In your case, you are splitting on one or more characters of whitespace and/or punctuation, and capturing the last of those characters to include in the split parts, which seems kind of a weird thing to do.  I'd have expected you might want to capture all of the separator, which would look like `r"([-\s.,;!?]+)"` (capturing one or more characters whitespace/punctuation characters, rather than matching one or more but only capturing the last).